# How to make input and select to be same width in css

Tags: html, css, select, input, tags

In my page, there are several `input` and `select` tags.

I use `width:100%;` to define their width, but the width in the browser is not `100%`.

I used the debug tool in chrome, and found there is also useragent stylesheet styles applied.

How can I make the width 100%?

Comment: what have you found in the useragent stylesheet?

Comment: i found the input&select tags have different border value.

Comment: how can i reset the user agent stylesheet of input&select.

Comment: Refer to [css-reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Us5pB/)

You should ideally separate style from content, so in your CSS include:

```
input, select{
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

nb. [demo fiddle *without* box-sizing set](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Us5pB/1/)

And you need to use `box-sizing:border-box` in order for sizing to take into account any browser specific or set margin/padding/borders. [Here's a handy read on the subject.](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

[Box-Sizing on MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

> The box-sizing CSS property is used to alter the default CSS box model
>   used to calculate widths and heights of elements. It is possible to
>   use this property to emulate the behavior of browsers that do not
>   correctly support the CSS box model specification.
>
> **border-box**
>
> The width and height properties include the padding and border, but
>   not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when
>   the document is in Quirks mode.

Comment: `box-sizing:border-box` saved the day

Answer (score 0):

To override the user agent stylesheet use **reset.css** in your code at the start.

```
   /* 
      Reset .css
   */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

If you do not want to override the useragent then you can go for width value in 'px'

Answer (score -1):

or use the following css:

```
input[type=text], select { 
    width: 100% //or whatever you want)
}
```

Comment: i have try this.But input&select's width are different.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use the width CSS property of select tag as follows:

```
<Select name="foo" width="100" style="width: 100px">
 <option>One</option>
 <option>Two</option>
 <option>Three</option>
 <option>Four</option>
</select>
```

So the same for the input tag

```
<input type="text" name="faa" value="test" style="width: 100px;" />
```

You can use the style in css as well for input tag.