# Vertical align input and select from different rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have simple html:

```
 <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
        <select class="form-control input-sm">
            <option value="0">NEW</option>
            <option value="1">PROCESSING</option>
            <option value="2">SHIPPED</option>
            <option value="3">COMPLETED</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

But, input is bigger than select. Can you explain me why?
This is [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jeqafefabu/edit?html,output)
PS. I can't change rows.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655786/how-to-make-input-and-select-to-be-same-width-in-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's depending to your select box's value length, I'm not expert in bootstrap but at all if you want to solve your problem you should make a little change in your code:

```
select.input-sm {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right!important;
    width: 50%;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eLtL6jqq/)

Answer (score 0):

See, in HTML, input fields have in-built  fixed width. So you have to override or use width property in css to increase the size of the input field. Let me know if you want to change the width.