# style="width:100%;" does not apply to <select> dropdown box in JavaFX

Tags: select, javafx, webview

```
[javaFX project > Main.class]
Stage stage = new Stage();      
WebView view = new WebView();
WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
engine.load(CONTEXTPATH + "/bddprAsist/smallCustlab");      // ==> load smallCustlab.jsp page

StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().add(view);

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 162, 364);

stage.setTitle("미니분석실");
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/img/ico-thebis-64x64.png"));
stage.setResizable(false);
stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
stage.show();
```

Load the smallCustlab.jsp web page via webview.

```
[webproject > smallCustlab.jsp]
<select id="select-style1" style="width:100%;">
    <c:forEach items="${SESSION_ATTRIBUTE.custInfo.custBizList}" var="custBiz">
        <option style="box-sizing:'content-box';width: 100%;" value="${custBiz.id}" selected="${custBiz.mainBizYn eq 'Y' ? 'selected' : ''}" data-bizNo="${custBiz.bizNo}">${custBiz.cmpNm}</option>
    </c:forEach>                    
</select>
```

But the width value of the dropdown box is not 100%
Also selected is not selected in the list ...

===> output image

[image]

Comment: Does it work in another web browser? If not - it is probably a CSS problem rather than a JavaFX one. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655786/how-to-make-input-and-select-to-be-same-width-in-css

Comment: Normal operation in browser....How can I make the width 100% in JavaFX?